# How to trigger a keyup event when testing angular material input field

Tags: angular, testing, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine

**I am trying to test if my search field upon keyup event updates the displayed values, based on the search string**

I found that `angular-material` provides great way of getting the element you need - `loader.getHarness/loader.getAllHarnesses` and a great set of methods to use on a harness to trigger the element behavior - `await myElement.setValue('some value')`. But I'm having a problem triggering a key up event. Currently in working with mocked data.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="search-field">
    <input
      matInput
      type="search"
      placeholder="search restaurant..."
      (keyup)="getSearchResults($event)"
    />
    <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**getSearchResults**

```
 getSearchResults(event: Event): void {
    const query = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.allRestaurants$ = of(query).pipe(
      map((query: string) => query.trim().toLowerCase()),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((query) => this.restaurantService.getAllRestaurants(query))
    );
  }
```

**Service**

```
getAllRestaurants(query?: string): Observable<RestaurantOverview[]> {
    if (query && query !== '') {
      return of(
        MockData.allHomeViewRestaurants.filter((restaurnat) =>
          restaurnat.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(query)
        )
      );
    }
    return of(MockData.allHomeViewRestaurants);
  }
```

**Failing test**

```
it('Should return only Random House Bistro card with search value of "bistro"', async () => {
      const searchField = await loader.getHarness(MatInputHarness);
      await searchField.setValue('bistro');
      const host = await searchField.host();
      await host.dispatchEvent('keyup');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const cards = await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatCardHarness);
      expect(cards.length).toEqual(1);
    });
```

**Test result**

```
debug.js:21 Expected 5 to equal 1.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/restaurant/overview/overview.component.spec.ts:138:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add stackblitz here?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done as follows:

```
const formField = <HTMLElement>fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.search-field')).nativeElement;
const htmlInput = <HTMLInputElement>formField.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0];
htmlInput.value = 'bistro';

const event: any = document.createEvent('Event');
event.key = 'o';
event.initEvent('keyup');
htmlInput.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also try to use the MatInputHarness for enter a value and trigger an event. In my case, the form field is triggered by 'blur'. And so it works like expected from me:

```
const input = await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatInputHarness)
    .then(harness => harness[0]);

await input.setValue('10');
input.blur();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

In my case, this is working. But I'm missing a kind of an input.change() event or in your case: input.keyup().

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the keyUp event that you want:

```js
async setValue(newValue: string): Promise<void> {
    const inputEl = await this.host();
    await inputEl.clear();
    ....
    if (newValue) {
      await inputEl.sendKeys(newValue);
    }

    ...
    await inputEl.setInputValue(newValue);
  }
```

in my test case .spec.ts I use:

```js
 (await input.host()).sendKeys('3');
 (await input.host()).dispatchEvent('change');
```

This set the value and triggers the change event. In my optinion is dispatchEvent a missing method in material testing class.

I found it in the testing lib in the angular repo:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/input/testing/input-harness.ts